# Table of contents [toc]: Variable tocdepth within toc when using multiple tables of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I can universally vary the table of contents depth.
This is typically handled with command:`\setcounter{tocdepth}{ [depth] }`.

I can partially vary the table of contents depth.
This is instead handled with package:`tocvsec2`.

I can create separate tables of contents, such as global and sectional.
This is handled with package:`titletoc`.

Currently, using `tocvsec2` to vary `tocdepth` affects all `titletoc` tocs.
I would like separate [partially-varied `tocdepth` parameters] for separate [tocs].

### MWE Explanation

In the MWE,

- `Item 1` has subsections `ABC`, each with subsubsections `xyz`.
- `Item 2` has subsections `IIa` and `IIb` Each mimics `Item 1`.
- `Item 3` mimics `Item 1`.
- `Item 4` has subsections `xyz`.

What is desired from the MWE,

- The `global` table of contents (first) should include `Item` and `ABC` sections.

  - This occurs.
- The `global` table of contents (first) should exclude `xyz` subsections.

  - This occurs.
- Each `sectional` table of contents (all others) should exclude other top-level sections.

  - This occurs.
- Each `sectional` table of contents (all others) should include other subsections.

  - This does not occur.
  - The `xyz` sections are blocked, like the global section.

The MWE is lengthy. Apologies.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{geometry}                   % margin/page layout settings
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}           % improved header commands. [supercedes `fancyhdr' package].

\usepackage{titletoc}                   % sub-[tables of contents]
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}        % hyperlinks.

\usepackage{tocvsec2}                   % variable depth in table of contents


% Margin Settings:
\newlength{\xhmargin   } \setlength{\xhmargin   }{0.750in}
\newlength{\xtmargin   } \setlength{\xtmargin   }{0.750in}
\newlength{\xbmargin   } \setlength{\xbmargin   }{0.750in}
\newlength{\xheadheight} \setlength{\xheadheight}{2.700em}
\newlength{\xheadsep   } \setlength{\xheadsep   }{1.000em}
\newlength{\xfootheight} \setlength{\xfootheight}{2.700em}
\newlength{\xfootskip  } \setlength{\xfootskip  }{3.700em} % [ = Footheight + Footsep]

\KOMAoptions{fontsize   = 12pt         ,
             parskip    = half-        ,
             headheight = \xheadheight , 
             footheight = \xfootheight , 
             DIV        = current      }

\geometry{letterpaper                ,
          hmargin      = \xhmargin   ,
          tmargin      = \xtmargin   ,
          bmargin      = \xbmargin   ,
          headsep      = \xheadsep   ,
          footskip     = \xfootskip  }

%Initialize headers and footers
\chead{\normalfont Header 1 \\ Header 2}
\cfoot{\normalfont Footer 1 \\ Footer 2}
\ofoot{\normalfont Page \thepage}


%Setup section numbering: Make \paragraph like \subsubsection.
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subsubsubsection}{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
            {-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}%
            {1.25ex \@plus .25ex}%
            {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother


%Setup section numbering: Make \paragraph and \subparagraph numbered.
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}   {5}





\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\settocdepth{subsection}

\section{Item I}

\startcontents[Item I]
\printcontents[Item I]{}{1}{ \subsection*{Contents} }

\clearpage

\subsection{A}
\subsubsection{x}
\subsubsection{y}
\subsubsection{z}

\clearpage

\subsection{B}
\subsubsection{x}
\subsubsection{y}
\subsubsection{z}

\clearpage

\subsection{C}
\subsubsection{x}
\subsubsection{y}
\subsubsection{z}

\stopcontents[Item I]


\clearpage

\settocdepth{subsubsection}

\section{Item II}

\startcontents[Item II]
\printcontents[Item II]{}{2}{ \subsection*{Contents} }

\clearpage


\subsection{Item IIa}


\clearpage


\subsubsection{A}
\subsubsubsection{x}
\subsubsubsection{y}
\subsubsubsection{z}

\clearpage

\subsubsection{B}
\subsubsubsection{x}
\subsubsubsection{y}
\subsubsubsection{z}

\clearpage

\subsubsection{C}
\subsubsubsection{x}
\subsubsubsection{y}
\subsubsubsection{z}


\clearpage


\subsection{Item IIb}


\clearpage

\subsubsection{A}
\subsubsubsection{x}
\subsubsubsection{y}
\subsubsubsection{z}

\clearpage

\subsubsection{B}
\subsubsubsection{x}
\subsubsubsection{y}
\subsubsubsection{z}

\clearpage

\subsubsection{C}
\subsubsubsection{x}
\subsubsubsection{y}
\subsubsubsection{z}

\stopcontents[Item II]

\clearpage

\settocdepth{subsection}

\section{Item III}

\startcontents[Item III]
\printcontents[Item III]{}{1}{ \subsection*{Contents} }

\clearpage

\subsection{A}
\subsubsection{x}
\subsubsection{y}
\subsubsection{z}

\clearpage

\subsection{B}
\subsubsection{x}
\subsubsection{y}
\subsubsection{z}

\clearpage

\subsection{C}
\subsubsection{x}
\subsubsection{y}
\subsubsection{z}

\stopcontents[Item III]

\clearpage

\settocdepth{section}

\section{Item IV}

\startcontents[Item IV]
\printcontents[Item IV]{}{1}{ \subsection*{Contents} }

\clearpage

\subsection{x}
\subsection{y}
\subsection{z}

\stopcontents[Item IV]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can a mod please create add the tag for tocvsec2 in this post? I don't have the rep to add it.

Comment: is `tocvsec2` necessary? I think `titletoc` does what you want.

Comment: use of `titletoc` is not recommanded with Koma class

Comment: @touhami : I don't think so. How so? [I reskimmed the documentation in case I missed something, but I didn't see anything new.]

Comment: 1) what do you mean  `I don't think so`? 2) do you really need koma class?

Comment: @touhami : ignore the koma class for now. it's unrelated to the problem.

Comment: @touhami : I do not think that `titletoc` does what I want.  `Tocvsec2` allows different depths for different items within the same table of contents.  If `titletoc` is active such that multiple tables of contents exist, the one set of `tocvsec2` rules affects ALL tables of contents.  I would like to use `tocvsec2` to create a set of varying-precision depth rules for one table of contents and a different set of varying-precision depth rules for a separate table of contents.  Varying-precision depth rules cannot be made without `tocvsec2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to replace

```
\settocdepth{subsection}

\section{Item I}

\startcontents[Item I]
\printcontents[Item I]{}{1}{ \subsection*{Contents} }
```

by

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}  %for first table

\startcontents
\section{Item I}

\addtocontents{ptc}{\string\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}  % for sections tables
\printcontents{}{1}{\subsection*{Contents}}
```

**Note:** don't use `\stopcontents`

**Complete code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}                   % sub-[tables of contents]
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}        % hyperlinks.

\newlength{\xhmargin   } \setlength{\xhmargin   }{0.750in}
\newlength{\xtmargin   } \setlength{\xtmargin   }{0.750in}
\newlength{\xbmargin   } \setlength{\xbmargin   }{0.750in}
\newlength{\xheadheight} \setlength{\xheadheight}{2.700em}
\newlength{\xheadsep   } \setlength{\xheadsep   }{1.000em}
\newlength{\xfootheight} \setlength{\xfootheight}{2.700em}
\newlength{\xfootskip  } \setlength{\xfootskip  }{3.700em} % [ = Footheight + Footsep]


\geometry{letterpaper                ,
          hmargin      = \xhmargin   ,
          tmargin      = \xtmargin   ,
          bmargin      = \xbmargin   ,
          headsep      = \xheadsep   ,
          footskip     = \xfootskip  }



%Setup section numbering: Make \paragraph like \subsubsection.
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subsubsubsection}{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
            {-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}%
            {1.25ex \@plus .25ex}%
            {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother


%Setup section numbering: Make \paragraph and \subparagraph numbered.
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}   {5}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage


%--------------------------------
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}

\startcontents
\section{Item I}

\addtocontents{ptc}{\string\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
\printcontents{}{1}{\subsection*{Contents}}
%--------------------------------

\clearpage

\subsection{A}
\subsubsection{x}
\subsubsection{y}
\subsubsection{z}

\clearpage

\subsection{B}
\subsubsection{x}
\subsubsection{y}
\subsubsection{z}

\clearpage

\subsection{C}
\subsubsection{x}
\subsubsection{y}
\subsubsection{z}



\clearpage


%--------------------------------
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}

\startcontents
\section{Item II}

\addtocontents{ptc}{\string\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}}
\printcontents{}{1}{\subsection*{Contents}}
%--------------------------------

\clearpage


\subsection{Item IIa}


\clearpage


\subsubsection{A}
\subsubsubsection{x}
\subsubsubsection{y}
\subsubsubsection{z}

\clearpage

\subsubsection{B}
\subsubsubsection{x}
\subsubsubsection{y}
\subsubsubsection{z}

\clearpage

\subsubsection{C}
\subsubsubsection{x}
\subsubsubsection{y}
\subsubsubsection{z}


\clearpage


\subsection{Item IIb}


\clearpage

\subsubsection{A}
\subsubsubsection{x}
\subsubsubsection{y}
\subsubsubsection{z}

\clearpage

\subsubsection{B}
\subsubsubsection{x}
\subsubsubsection{y}
\subsubsubsection{z}

\clearpage

\subsubsection{C}
\subsubsubsection{x}
\subsubsubsection{y}
\subsubsubsection{z}


\clearpage

%--------------------------------
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}

\startcontents
\section{Item III}

\addtocontents{ptc}{\string\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
\printcontents{}{1}{\subsection*{Contents}}
%--------------------------------

\clearpage

\subsection{A}
\subsubsection{x}
\subsubsection{y}
\subsubsection{z}

\clearpage

\subsection{B}
\subsubsection{x}
\subsubsection{y}
\subsubsection{z}

\clearpage

\subsection{C}
\subsubsection{x}
\subsubsection{y}
\subsubsection{z}


\clearpage

%--------------------------------
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}

\startcontents
\section{Item IV}

\addtocontents{ptc}{\string\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
\printcontents{}{1}{\subsection*{Contents}}
%--------------------------------

\clearpage

\subsection{x}
\subsection{y}
\subsection{z}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Color me impressed. 1: How can you newline in a comment? 2: Why is \string necessary? 3: Why should \stopcontents be avoided? 4: Does using KOMA specifically affect this issue?

Comment: For reference, I tested the code without the \string [2] without issue. I tested the code with \stopcontents [3] and with toc labels, without issue. I tested the code with KOMA [4], without issue.

Comment: NOTE: When using labels for partial tocs, I would avoid spaces despite my MWE.  Even when using toc labels, the code to alter depth for a partial toc remains `\addtocontents{ptc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{ [DEPTH] }}` regardless of toc label.

Comment: What I understand: `\string` not necessary here but  it 's good idea for general writing to another file. in my MWE `\starcontents` will call `stopcontents`. I am not a KOMA user so I can't tell what is the problem but it is will known that titletoc(sec) break some feature of KOMA class.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: Is there a good guide for instances to use `\string`?

Comment: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/plain/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf

Comment: Already encountered an issue when not using `\string`. Received error "Undefined control sequence" with code `\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{ [DEPTH] }}`.  You're the champ, tou.